# Maven/Junit Parallel Execution - Cucumber-JVM v4.0.0

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm struggling to get the new parallel execution feature of Cucumber-JVM v4.0.0 working with JUnit/Maven.

As specified [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/v4.0.0/junit), if you configure `<parallel>` and `<threadCount>` accordingly in your POM, and use dependency injection to share state (I'm using Pico Continer) then your Cucumber features should execute in parallel.

However, it is still only executing one feature at a time when i run Maven.

I've included my complete POM below - Can anybody help?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.softwareautomation</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>selenium</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>both</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- AssertJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Cucumber -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Selenium WebDriver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

If it helps, below is my runner class (com.softwareautomation.world is the DI class)

```
package com.evasoftwareautomation.runners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "junit:target/cucumber.xml"},
        features = "src/test/resources/com/softwareautomation/features",
        glue = {"com.softwareautomation.stepdefs", "com.softwareautomation.world"},
        junit ={ "--step-notifications"},
        monochrome = true)
public class CucumberTest {
}
```

Please see failing stack trace when running from Maven below:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Concurrency config is parallel='methods', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=4, useUnlimitedThreads=false
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.junit.runner.Description.createSuiteDescription(Description.java:124)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit48.FilterFactory$GroupMatcherCategoryFilter.shouldRun(FilterFactory.java:207)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.shouldRun(ParentRunner.java:434)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:382)
        at org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.apply(Filter.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:384)
        at org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.apply(Filter.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:384)
        at org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.apply(Filter.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:384)
        at org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.apply(Filter.java:97)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:37)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreWrapper.execute(JUnitCoreWrapper.java:62)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreProvider.invoke(JUnitCoreProvider.java:139)
        ... 9 more

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.709 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-25T23:36:01+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project selenium: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: Are you sure that the parallel options should be added to the `maven-compiler-plugin`?

Comment: Your right, i have re-configured to POM but now getting the below error when i run:
`Concurrency config is parallel='both', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=4, useUnlimitedThreads=false
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: @mpkorstanje i have updated my new POM in the above question

Comment: I don't know. You should also include the full stack trace in your post.

Comment: @mpkorstanje added stack trace

Comment: Have you considered updating your maven surefire plugin?

Comment: I did not consider. I have upgraded, and now it's working. Thanks so much for your help @mpkorstanje - if the above is made into an answer, i will accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit48.FilterFactory$GroupMatcherCategoryFilter.shouldRun(FilterFactory.java:207)
```

You are using JUnit 4.12. However as noted above the stack trace tells us that surefire is trying to use an integration for JUnit 4.8. Your version of surefire was released in 2012, where as JUnit 4.12 was released in 2014. Have you considered updating your maven surefire plugin?

Comment: Updated Maven Surefire and it's now running, and running like a dream! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by explicitly adding the dependency of the testing framework:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <configuration>
    <parallel>all</parallel>
    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it here as it might help somebody else

In my case

- maven was not picking up Junit 5 tests
- cucumber tests were not running in parallel

Got it working by

- adding junit-jupiter 5.5.2
- adding maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2 and explicitly adding
  surefire-junit47 2.22.2

  ```
          <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.2</version>
          <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                  <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                  <version>2.22.2</version>
              </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <configuration>
              <parallel>both</parallel>
              <threadCount>4</threadCount>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```

Comment: Are you able to control the threadCount ? Example I am giving 2 as thread count but its running 4.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using surefire 2.12.4 and updating it to 2.22.2 did the trick