# Parallel Execution not happening with Cucumber JVM 4.0.0 and Junit test runner

Tags: java, junit, cucumber-jvm

I am unable to run features in parallel using cucumber JVM 4.0.0 and Junit testrunner. I just have one browser instance opening and once the execution is completed, browser closes and opens again for next feature execution.As per my thread count of 3 in Maven surefire, i expect 3 browser instances to be opened concurrently for running 3 features. I have followed the following [link](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/v4.0.0/junit), but still not successful. The Features run one after another. I have used Pico container for DI.I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998443/maven-junit-parallel-execution-cucumber-jvm-v4-0-0) for updating different version of Surefire plugin but still no luck. i have tried 4.0.0 as well as 4.2.0 for IO.cucumber Jars. I have tried different versions of surefire from 2.19 to 2.22 but still no luck.I have 3 features files and each of them have one scenario outline tagged as "@Parallel".I am not sure where am going wrong.I have tried parallel as "both" and "methods" in surefire plugin. My Junit version is 4.12.

My pom is as below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>testcase</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyzproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xyzproject</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <cocumber.version>4.0.0</cocumber.version>
        <picocontainer.version>4.0.0</picocontainer.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Central Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.bodar.com</id>
            <url>http://repo.bodar.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cocumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cocumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cocumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cocumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>or.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-spis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cocumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cocumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--REPORTING -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.totallylazy</groupId>
            <artifactId>totallylazy</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.totallylazy</groupId>
            <artifactId>totallylazy</artifactId>
            <version>1.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compailer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadcount>3</threadcount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cocumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.7</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.googlecode.totallylazy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>totallylazy</artifactId>
                        <version>991</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <projectname>cucumber-jvm-example</projectname>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/cocumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cocumberoutput>${project.build.directory}/cocumber.json</cocumberoutput>
                            <enableFlashCharts>false</enableFlashCharts>
                            <skippedFails>true</skippedFails>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My testrunner is as below.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report",
"json:target/cucumber.json","pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
"usage:target/cucumber-usage.json, "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml"},
features={"src/test/resources/featuresfiles"},strict=false,dryRun=false,
glue={"Stepdef_new.stepdefinitions"},
tags={"@Parallel"}
}

Public class TestRunner{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be irrelevant .

I tried to implement to Cucumber with Junit and because  of **it's limitation of being parallel on  feature level** and I moved to Cucumber-TestNG.

TestNG it self supports Junit. So only runner class need to changed in current design

Please have a look this once https://github.com/bhargavQA/selenium-java-cucumber-framewrok.git

This is being done with **Cucumber TestNG** and supports parallel execution at scenario level.

Comment: The Link is not Working.

Comment: please try this https://github.com/bhargavQA/selenium-java-cucumber-framewrok.git

Comment: Does this support AppiumDriver for mobile?

Comment: The question was asked for Cucumber, JUnit, you answered Cucumber, TestNG. Do you have a correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the testng dependency or to explicitly say to use the surefire-junit
like

```
<plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire.version}</version>

                        <configuration>
                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>20</threadCount>
                            <!-- <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads> -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/JUnitRunner.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>


                        <dependencies>
                            <!-- https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html 
                                - You can also manually force a specific provider by adding it as a dependency 
                                to Surefire itself: -->
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                                <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>

                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
```

Try this:
https://github.com/rhapsodyman/cucumber4-parallel

Comment: Adding the dependency fixed it. Thanks for solving my 1 hour of debugging

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have meant to use `maven-surefire-plugin` instead of `maven-surefire-report-plugin` in your configuration.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadcount>3</threadcount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I have changed surefire config in my original question. I have been using only surefire & not report plugin in my Pom..

Answer (score 0):

You should be using maven-failsafe-plugin, not surefire.
I used failsafe in combination with com.github.temyers -cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin

Comment: Cucumber supports parallel execution since v4.0.0. The parallel plugin is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (trying enabling parallel in pom but features seem to run in sequence).

While searching I found this bug https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/987 claiming that the parallel and threadcount configuration is ignored in maven with testng. I then realized that I had a dependency to testng while I was not using it at all (apart from some assertions that I switched to use junit).

I can see in your pom a dependency to testng. You could try remove the dependency or ensure you use one version having the testng issue fixed and try again.